# Bottom navigation bar hides part of a view

Tags: android

In my app I want to display a simple Image,

On my Samsung Galaxy S7 Real device the image is fine, The bottom Navigation bar is not part of the view but part of the phone itself. 
The whole of the Image is present.

On the Android Emulator the bottom navigation bar is part of the view and the image is partially hidden

Here is my simple Linear Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:background="@color/md_blue_50"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_image_large"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Android Emulator Screenshot

[android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEGqj.jpg)

Here is my Samsung Galaxy Real Device Screenshot

[android real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ZKe.jpg)

The problem also occurs in recycler Views in the app the bottom part of the image is cut off on the android emulator...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of `android:fitSystemWindows` put it to false and it should be good

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with BottomNavigationView (menu) this is solution :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">  
</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/color_main_white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/color_main_white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
```

Try to change parameter android:layout_heigh to 0dp and add this  android:layout_weight="1" for ImageView

Answer (score 0):

you have to place the view above the bottom navigation bar so that the view wont hide in the bottom navigation bar

Comment: But the bottom navigation bar is not even part of the view - please refer to my LinearLayout...

Comment: yeah i understood its an android emulator its not real device so there is no problem when you are putting the app in play store

Comment: Just tried android:fitsSystemWindows="false" the image is still the same

Comment: shall u post the screen shot